# Which is more flexible? django-registration or django-userena

Tags: python, django, django-registration

I am looking to users of django-userena and django-registration (which I think is more popular) to answer this. I have checked out the docs for both and I am still not completely sold on either choice.

Due to the way django handles userprofiles (at least, django < 1.5) I need to know which app is more suitable for my fairly common requirements:

1. Two types of user models each with different attributes and methods (e.g. Student and Teacher)
2. @login_required decorators (@teacher_login_required and @student_login_required) and easy access to the Teacher or Student object via request.teacher or request.student
3. Email login with email activation for Teacher accounts and username login (standard) for Student accounts with email activation not required.
4. Different urls for teacher accounts and student accounts (signup, login, settings).

Comment: I have the exact same issue, and what I've been using so far is [django-email-as-username](https://github.com/dabapps/django-email-as-username), combined with some pretty complex subclassing of `User` and proxy classes I set up.  My conclusion is that Django<=1.4 sucks for this and I'm waiting for Django 1.5 to be released.  It's absurd how difficult it is to have different kinds of users.  I'm astounded, frankly.  See my previous question [here](https://github.com/dabapps/django-email-as-username).

Comment: @jdotjdot thanks for django-email-as-username. will check it out. i am not sure when django 1.5's stable release is out. guess i'll have to wait n see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your case I would recommend you to try django-registration since its much more modular and simpler to hack. Django-userena is good but it comes with a full package such as thumbnails which I don't think you will need. In any case you can take a look at a good comparison at https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/registration/.

Comment: I ended up going with django-registration. Saved me a lot of time!

Comment: yes, and if you want to extend to userprofile you can use django userprofile by the same developer of django registration. Both of these are very pluggable.

Comment: @ambrex do you have any working example of the solution you've reached with django-registration?